# Some method, for using javascript output in inline css?

Tags: javascript

I thought, would be cozy, if I can use an script output in inline css for max-height value from the current screen height, suchlike this:

I get the current screen's height with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
gmodal = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
ymodal = w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||gmodal.clientHeight;</script>
```

But, any method, that I can use this in inline css, like:

`<div style="max-height:'{ymodal}'">`

Comment: Looks like you're having a case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/306392) there. I don't know any CSS but there's probably a way to achieve your result without any use of JS.

Comment: You can do the equivalent of this in many/most frameworks such as Angular, where one might write `<div [style.max-height]="ymodal">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max-height: 100vh;` to get an element to be the height of the inner window height.

If you still need to insert a JavaScript variable into a css property, you are probably going to need to use `element.style.*`

```
<div id='some-id'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        gmodal = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        ymodal = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || gmodal.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById('some-id').style.maxHeight = ymodal + 'px';
</script>
```

Note the `+ 'px'` and using `maxHeight` instead of `max-height`

Comment: lol, I very overcomplicated this, the best solution is the `max-height: 100vh;`